# An alternative way to get console output of system() function

Tags: c, linux, gnu

While executing below code in a console:

```
int ret = system("iptables -t filter -L");
```

`ret` will get value `1` and there will be a list of rules displayed in the console.
The problem is that I also want to get the list of rules inside my program. I am doing this with the below solution:

```
int ret = system("iptables -t filter -L >> filter-table.txt");
/* read filter-table.txt file to get the list */
```

Is there anyway else to get the list?

Comment: ...by using a popen()-family function rather than `system()`?

Comment: ...seriously, though: If you want output, system() is the wrong call. (If you want detailed control over argv parsing, or immunity from shellshock-style vulnerabilities, system() is _also_ the wrong call. I'd argue that it's only very rarely the *right* call, personally).

Comment: `system()` is primarily useful for writing shell scripts in languages other than the shell and proof-of-concept security exploits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @Charles Duffy, and @Kevin, `system()` is not the function you want.  `popen()` is more suitable.  The following should work.  Please note, if you are using `gcc` and compile with `-std=c99` flag, you need to add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2` before `#include <stdio.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>

#define PATH_MAX 1024

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  int status;
  char path[PATH_MAX];

  fp = popen("iptables -t filter -L", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    perror("popen");
    return -1;
  }

  while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s", path);
    /* do something you want with the return data */
  }


  status = pclose(fp);
  if (status == -1) 
  {
    perror("pclose");
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install iptables-devel on your distro and directly include de library in your code to build something cleaner. In place of using the output.

You'll find an hint on this link :
http://www.bani.com.br/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/

Comment: Libiptc does not exist anymore. Check the last question and answer at http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq.html#toc4.5